# Example of radial frequency functions that give scale shiftability

Tags: wavelet

[Simoncelli's "Shiftable multi-scale transforms" paper](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/simoncelli91-reprint.pdf) talks about shiftability of the parameters of a wavelet transform, in particular translation, rotation and scale. The first two are used in his steerable pyramid decomposition.

Can anyone point to an example of a filterbank used for the latter - scale shiftability? I have used sin and cos (Fourier series) as radial basis functions, but I wonder if there is a better set that have been optimised for some property, e.g. space-frequency localisation.

Comment: Interesting. I'm also working on Wavelets and try to find ideal Filter Bank.

Comment: @Drazick For the same purpose? This is some preliminary work I have done: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282337162_Scale_Adaptive_Filters